# Scope of appended elements

Tags: arrays, c, size-t

I am writing a C program that, for a given array, will split it into two arrays, which will contain elements smaller or greater than a certain user-defined value.

The problem is that whilst my for loop does create the correct lists, which can be seen by inserting a printf statement like so:

```
if(iList_1[n] <= boarder){
    iList_2small[step_L2] = iList_1[n];
    printf("%i ", iList_2small[step_L2]);
    step_L2 += 1;
}
```

**It seems to me that this list is only within the scope of the first for loop.** Because when I try to print the lists after all elements have been identified, the list somehow contains seemingly no elements as indicated by `size_t len2 = sizeof(iList_2small)/sizeof(int);` returning  `len2 = 0`. Or is simply equal to the original list, as indicated by the fact that I can print out every one of the 11 elements of the original array `printf("\n\n%i\n\n", iList_2small[10]);` printing `56`.

This problem is really confusing me as I according my Python knowledge this should work. However this being C, it doesn't. That's the code:

```
// Dividing a List into two Lists who's elements are <=X or >X
int main()
{
    int n;
    int boarder;
    int iList_1[] = {1, 23, 15, 90, 78, 234, 987, 2, 0, 13, 56};
    int iList_2small[] = {};
    int iList_3large[] = {};

    //Calculate the number of elements in the array
    size_t len1 = sizeof(iList_1) / sizeof(int);
    printf("The Array iList_1 is %llu long\n", len1);

    //Where to divide the array?
    printf("At what value should the array iList_1 be split? (ONLY INEGERS ALLOWED)\n");
    scanf("%i", &boarder);
    printf("\nConfirming boarder value of: %i \n\n", boarder);

    //Dividing the arrays at the boarder value
    for(n=0; n < len1; n++){
        int step_L2 = 0;
        int step_L3 = 0;

        if(iList_1[n] <= boarder){
            iList_2small[step_L2] = iList_1[n];
            step_L2 += 1;
        }
        else if(iList_1[n] > boarder){
            iList_3large[step_L3] = iList_1[n];
            step_L3 += 1;
        }
    }

    //Computing the length of the sorted arrays
    size_t len2 = sizeof(iList_2small)/sizeof(int);
    size_t len3 = sizeof(iList_3large)/sizeof(int);

    //Only for demonstration purposes
    printf("\nThe length of the second list is \t %llu \t elements", len2);
    printf("\nThe length of the second list is \t %llu \t elements\n", len3);
    printf("\n\n%i\n\n", iList_2small[10]);

    //Outputting the sorted arrays
    for(n = 0; n < 8 ; n++){
        printf("%i ", iList_2small[n]);
    }

    for(n = 0; n < len3; n++){
        printf("%i", iList_3large[n]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then how can I declare an array of an yet unknown length? And why art there elements being appended to it within the loop is it has no "placeholders" for the elements?

Comment: You can't declare arrays of as yet unknown length in C.  C is _not_ Python.  You have to manage the array sizes explicitly, and you have to know how big they're going to be.  With caution, you could consider using VLAs — variable-length arrays; the care is required to make sure you don't overflow the stack.  With care to release the allocated memory, you could consider using dynamically allocated memory.  That covers most of the plausible generic solutions.  Using fixed size arrays won't work well if the array size increases from tens to thousands or millions or more elements.

Comment: Note that in strict standard C, `int iList_2small[] = {};` is not valid syntax — it is using C++ syntax, but some compilers (GCC, and Clang emulating GCC) allow it in C code, even though standard C says "No".  You have a zero-size array (not allowed in C) and you have an empty pair of braces as an initialized (also not allowed in C).